# Adding an App to the List Sharable Files [iTunes]

Tags: iphone, itunes, email, file-sharing

I looked in Google for a long time for "Adding an app to the list of sharable file", but I didn´t find anything.

When I open **File Sharing** in **iTunes** I can see the following apps:
[image]

I wanna add the *mail* app to the above list. Can anyone points me towards a guide for doing that?

Comment: This list will only show apps that support file sharing. If an application is installed on the device and it's not on that list, it doesn't support file sharing through itunes. Maybe the relatively new [File app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481) could get you closer to what you want? — You should perhaps further describe what you want to happen. Like are you trying to add emails to the mail app or are you trying to add files to the mail app so that you can easily attach them to outgoing emails?

Comment: Thanks @Joonas for your contribution! I had an email adr running on Outlook[windows OS] and mail[iPhone]. I changed the server adr in Outlook what leads to losting some important folders and emails. Because of that I am trying to rescue the emails from the iPhone. Could you provide me with some hints? thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know a whole lot about that. I use a third party mail app. You _may_ want to trash this question and make a new one more aimed towards getting those emails back. You might want to add some more details to that email, like which protocol the email uses: imap or pop3? Kinda sounds like it uses pop3. Also do the emails show up in your iphone, but not on your desktop machine?

Comment: @Joonas, thank you for the hint! see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316598/rescuing-emails-from-mail-iphone